# Check if Zip file is encrypted or password protected using PHP

Tags: php, passwords, zip

I am writing a scanner that will look for possibly hacked/malware files. One requirement is to  check if a zip (or any compressed) file is password-protected using some PHP function.

I don't want to add any extra software requirements, so should work on multiple servers, using PHP 5.3+ . (Yes I know that 5.3 is old, but the process may need to run on older PHP installations.) If this detection is available in newer PHP versions, then I could have code that would run only on newer PHP version.

I can use the `file_get_contents()` function to read the file's contents into a string. How do I check that string for an indication that the zip file is password-protected? Note that I don't want to uncompress the file, just check it for password-protection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code appears to work, but might be improved.

The process seems to involve two steps:

- use zip_open to open the file, returning a resource. No resource, zip couldn't be opened, so it might be passworded
- use zip_read to read the files inside the zip. If fails, then might be passworded

In either of those two cases, return true, indicating probable password on the zip file.

```
// try to open a zip file; if it fails, probably password-protected
function check_zip_password($zip_file = '') {
    /*
    open/read a zip file
    return true if passworded
     */
    if (!$zip_file) { // file not specified
        return false;
    }
    $zip = zip_open($zip_file);     // open the file
    if (is_resource($zip)) {        // file opened OK
        $zipfile = zip_read($zip);  // try read of zip file contents
        if (!$zipfile) { // couldn't read inside, so passworded
            return true;
            } 
            else 
            { // file opened and read, so not passworded
            return false;
        }
    } else { // couldn't open the file, might be passworded
        return true;
    }
    return false; // file exists, but not password protected
}
```

Note that the code only determines that the files inside the zip can't be accessed, so they are probably password-protected. The code doesn't try to do any processing of files inside the zip.

Comment: Thank you Rick Hellewell! I noticed there are subtle differences to be aware of when working with encrypted zip files. When using `zipcloak` (which encrypts previously compressed zip files), all items (files and directories) in the zip file carry the encryption flag. When using `zip -e` or `zip -P`, only files (but not directories) carry this flag. Unfortunately, your code fails in this second case (iff directories are present in the archive). One can check for the encryption flag using e.g. `zipinfo` (look for lines with capital `B` or `T`) or `zipdetails` (General purpose flag -> Bit #0 = 1)